# How to get the min value after an union in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, union, min

Let's say I have 2 tables A and B.

These 2 tables have 3 columns in common Name, Id and Price.

This is the query I used for 1 table :

```
SELECT Name, Id, Price FROM A WHERE Id = "123" and Price = (SELECT MIN(Price) FROM A);
```

I've just realised that this query doesn't work when the lowest price is held by another Id.

So I've look around and I think I should use GROUP BY ?

I've changed it to :

```
SELECT Name, MIN(Price) FROM A WHERE Id = "123" GROUP BY Name;
```

But this is not the expected result.

Let's say in table A I have :

| Name | Id | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Au | 123 | 12 |
| Be | 123 | 16 |
| St | 122 | 9 |
| Ge | 123 | 10 |

And for table B I have :

| Name | Id | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| La | 123 | 14.5 |
| La | 123 | 12 |
| St | 123 | 13 |
| Is | 123 | 12 |
| Is | 123 | 10 |
| La | 123 | 10 |
| Is | 123 | 10 |

And the expected result is :

| Name | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Ge | 10 |
| Is | 10 |
| La | 10 |

The expected result is 1 row long because in the set of data there is only one row that match the condition but if I had another row with a Price of 10 and an Id of 123 it should be there also. So if there are more rows that matched the condition I want them in the result.

The problem is that when I do the following query using UNION I don't know how to get the lowest price for a specific Id:

```
SELECT Name, Id, Price FROM A UNION SELECT Name, Id, Price FROM B;
```

So what can I add to my query to have the expected result and then how would it work if I use union to get the lowest price of a specific Id over 2 tables ?

Comment: I've edited my post to match my current data and what the expected result is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be ok for you:

```
select * 
from (select Name, id, Price FROM A
      union
      select Name, id, Price FROM B) Tab
where (Tab.id, Tab.price) = (select Tab2.id, min(Tab2.price)
                             from (select Name, id, Price FROM A
                                   union
                                   select Name, id, Price FROM B) Tab2
                             where Tab2.id = '123')
```

You have only one place where you put the ID you are looking for.

Here you can see the demo:
[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90f0f0d6a273c065a4beeec86653b12b)

```
/*This returns everything from your two tables*/
select * 
from (SELECT Name, id, Price FROM A
      union
      select Name, id, Price FROM B) Tab

/*this returns the minimal price for your requested ID, here you requested id =123*/
select Tab2.id, min(Tab2.price)
from (SELECT Name, id, Price FROM A
      union
      select Name, id, Price FROM B) Tab2
where Tab2.id = '123'

--with this where clause: 
where (Tab.id, Tab.price)
/*you are telling the query :
  give me every row from all the data(first query)that has 
  this combination of ID + PRICE: 
  123 + 10 (you have found this with the second query)

  So, you do not care what name it is, it only has to have :
  ID = 123 and the lowest price which is 10.
  ID 123 was requested from you and lowest price for that ID is 10,  
  which you have founded with the second query.*/
```

Comment: Hello @DataM here is my example. Cheers!

Comment: Can you break down the query so I can understand better and maybe next time try to find the solution on my own since i'll have more knowledge ? And why in this one there is no need of group by to return a single row per different Name ?

Comment: Hello @DataM I have added new data from your question to my demo...

Comment: Yes it helps a lot, thank you for your time, I have a better understanding how sql and subquery works. And hope my post will be useful for others and not just me.

Comment: Hello @DataM, I am happy that I was able to help.

Answer (score 3):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `RANK` here with a union query:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Name, Id, Price FROM A WHERE Id = '123'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, Id, Price FROM B WHERE Id = '123'
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY price) rnk
    FROM cte
)

SELECT Name, Id, Price
FROM cte2
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Here is a query which should work on earlier versions of MySQL:

```sql
SELECT Name, Id, Price
FROM
(
    SELECT Name, Id, Price FROM A WHERE Id = '123'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, Id, Price FROM B WHERE Id = '123'
) t
WHERE Price = (
    SELECT Price FROM A WHERE Id = '123'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Price FROM B WHERE Id = '123'
    ORDER BY Price
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I don't want to have a single record as output I actually want all the record that match my condition where i want the lowest Price value for a specific Id

Comment: @DataM If there could be more than one record, then I suggest using `RANK` here, q.v. my updated answer above.

Comment: i've tried the query in phpmyadmin but the result of the query is empty

Comment: @DataM I suspect that you're using a version of MySQL earlier than 8+.  In this case, I have given an alternative query which should still work.

Comment: I've tried it and it worked, you're right the version I have is below 8 but the version isn't displayed where it's supposed to be. If you can explain how the query works it would be very kind of you. Thank you very much !

Comment: The subquery following `WHERE` just finds the absolute minimum price for `Id = 123` from _both_ tables.  This is used to filter the records above in the union query.

Comment: Vote up. Here is my small demo where my complicated query :) (I am sure theer are much better ways to do it...) returns one result if there are two same records(Name, Id, Price) and this returns two of them. So, @DataM, you can select what you need : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a09fbeed4ef9d249690b046c07f3a84

Comment: I'm troubling you one last time is it possible to group them by Name in the result so instead of having 3 same records for the same Name it only display one by Name ?

Comment: @DataM you already have the min price, and the id. So you can do this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f9c4d88e98994c900d29d833569daf2

Comment: Sorry @DataM - check the last query in the fiddle I have sent above

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on db-fiddle.com and it returns all the rows with the lowest price:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Price
FROM (SELECT * FROM A UNION SELECT * FROM B) TMP
WHERE (Price, Id) = (
    SELECT MIN(Price), Id
    FROM (SELECT * FROM A UNION SELECT * FROM B) TMP2
    WHERE Id = "123"
);
```

Here are the script for the tables I tested the query against:

```
create table A(
   _id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Id  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   Price INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( _id )
);

create table B(
   _id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Id  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   Price INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( _id )
);

INSERT INTO A(Id, Name, Price)
VALUES
('123', 'Name123a1', 21),
('123', 'Name123a2', 41),
('124', 'Name124a', 40);

INSERT INTO B(Id, Name, Price)
VALUES
('123', 'Name123b1', 22),
('123', 'Name123b2', 21),
('124', 'Name124b', 20);
```

The solution took some time to figure out, because I am rusty. Thanks to VBoka that helped me with sorting out bugs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236484/discussion-between-vboka-and-gowiser).

Comment: You are right, I am too rusty with SQL. Thank you for helping me. I have adjusted the answer, and arrived at your solution - god damn.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this after your last query, the one that outputs 3 price values and you need the minimum.

- create a cte
- create a rank using `ROW_NUMBER` based on price in ASC order which is the default order if you want highest then add `DESC` in the end
- filter the data with that rank column

```
with data as (
    
select 
    *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER(ORDER BY price ) as rank_ from table
    )

select * from data where rank_ = 1
```